# Force Java to call my C++ destructor (JNI)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I thought this question would have been asked before, but I couldn't find it here...

I've used SWIG to create a JNI wrapper around a C++ class. All works great except that Java never seems to call the class's finalize(), so, in turn, my class's destructor never gets called. The class's destructor does some final file I/O, so unfortunately, this isn't just a minor memory leak.

Searching through Google, there doesn't seem to be a way to force Java to GC and destroy an object. True?

I know I could manipulate my SWIG file and create a java function that would call the C++ destructor, but this class is used by end users in several different platforms/languages, so the addition of a Java-only will create an inconsistency that our tech writers aren't going to like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't force GC with System.gc().
Also it is not guaranteed that there will ever be a GC run for example if your app runs only for a short time and then your finalizer won't run at all (the JVM does not run it when exiting). You should create a close() or destroy() or whatever function for your class and when you finished using an instance of this class call it, preferably from a finally block, like.

```
MyClass x = null;
try{
    x = new MyClass();
    x.work();
} finally {
    if (x!=null)
        x.close();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Java finalizers are mostly useless, in my opinion, and certainly not a replacement for C++ destructors.  Unfortunately, Java has no replacement for C++ RAII.

Don't bother trying to force Java finalization.  When you're through with the whatever, all a function that will dispose of it.  That's all you can do.

Answer (score 4):

If you're relying on code in the `finalize` method to run at a certain time, you need to reconsider your approach.  The problem here is that you don't know when `finalize` will be called by the JVM, since you don't know when the object will be garbage collected.

One thing that you should consider, since your class will be re-used in other projects, is that it's possible that an end-user could use an instance of a class in such a way that it will not be collected or that garbage collection will be unlikely, such as creating a static reference to an instance of the class.  I think creating a `close` or `destroy` method is your safest bet to ensure that the resources the instance of the C++ class associated with your Java object is using are released appropriately.

Since re-use is a concern, you could have the C++ destructor check to see if the resources had been released and to call the same code if they hadn't been, like so:

```
class MyThing {
  public:
    void close();
    ~MyThing();

  private:
    bool released = false;
};

void
MyThing::close() {
  // close logic here
  this->released = true;
}

MyThing::~MyThing() {
  if (!released) {
    this->close();
  }
}
```

This way, your existing C++ code hopefully won't have to change much, and you can ensure that your resources are released in a deterministic way in the context of native code running via JNI.

Answer (score 2):

After some more looking through the SWIG-produced code, I see that the SWIG people actually have already dealt with this -- they add a delete() function for you. It looks to pretty well taken care of the possibility of both the programmer and the GC deleting the object as well.

Answer (score -1):

Issues like this are the reason C# chose the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern for deterministic finalization.

I suggest you follow the same pattern and adapt it for your Java users.

In your c++ class, create a separate, public method that disposes of your resources. Call it close, or dispose, or something.

Have your C++ destructor call the public method, and tell managed/GC users of the C++ class that they must call the method to avoid memory leaks.